# Break Cpp loop with "|"

Tags: c++, string, types, int, type-conversion

My code reads an indefinite amount of integers, two at a time: `while (cin>>a>>b)`.

I want the loop to break when `|` is entered and assigned to either `a` or `b`.

`a` and `b` should both be declared as `int`. I would then compare: `a` or `b` `==int('|')`

Defining 'a' and 'b' as `char`type initially, allowed me to skirt the problem but isn't ideal.

This is the chapter 4 drill in Stroustrup's *Principles and practice using C++*(Pg. 124).

I think I understand that reading  `|` into an int variable is trying to convert a `string` into an `int`(not acceptable?). Stroustrup says to use the character to end the loop in his drill but he doesn't explain how he used it earlier when he mentioned it in the book. Is there actually a way to use the `|` character as required, using just basic code discussed up to that point in the book? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The character `|` is not a valid integer, so input will fail and your loop will break.  However, it will not be assigned to `a` or `b`.  If you want to process non-integer text, you need to read into a string or character.

Comment: No, `|` is really simply not an `int`. (Perhaps there is a `boost::glyph_cast` which will return `1`. I haven't looked into it.)

Comment: So `|` is **intended** to fail as input to break the loop? Haha. Well it was fun trying to process it all day. Thank you both.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary to use any specific character - any non-numeric, non-whitespace character will break the loop.

When `cin >> a >> b` is executed, it, as you know, reads two whitespace-separated integers into `a` and `b`, in order. The expression *returns* the `cin` object, so the whole expression has the value `cin`. This is important to note.

When `cin` is evaluated in a boolean context (like in an `if` statement or `while` loop), it is equivalent to calling `!cin.fail()`. That is, `cin` will evaluate as `true` when the stream is in a good state, but it evaluates to `false` when there has been an error.

When `cin` tries to read a `|` character into an `int` variable, the operation does not make sense, and therefore fails. `cin` then sets its fail flag. Because the fail flag is set, `cin.fail()` will return `true`, and when `cin` is evaluated as a boolean, it evaluates to `false`, and the loop ends.

It should be noted that after `cin` enters a fail state, its state needs to be reset and any unusable input discarded before `cin` can be used again:

```
cin.clear(); // reset state flags
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // discard all input up to next newline
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm curious, is there a way to use the false `cin` as a condition in and `if` or `switch` statement, so I can output "loop broken" or something?

Comment: @James: With an `if`, yes. A `switch` requires an integral expression - one that produces numbers, not `bool`. So a `switch` with two possible values (`0` and `default`) is not a particularly good use for a `switch`.